# sql fetch all messages

Tags: mysql, sql

I have achieved this sql statement:

```
SELECT users.firstname, users.lastname, users.screenname, profile.profile_pic,
users.user_id, messages.msgid, messages.message, messages.action,
DATE_FORMAT(messages.date_sent, '%M %d, %Y %r') AS date_sent
FROM messages messages
JOIN users ON messages.sent_by = users.user_id
LEFT JOIN profile ON (users.user_id = profile.user_id)
WHERE messages.recepient_id = "12052821" and messages.action = false
ORDER BY msgid DESC
```

And it outputs me the correct output (below) 
[image]

The problem is how do you sort out all the list of the users who messaged you and display the **top 1 messages ORDER BY by msgid DESC respectively**? (Users must not be repeated)

**Here are my tables** 
[image]

My query above needs a little bit of enhancement I guess. Thank you guys in advance

Answer (score 0):

Problem Solved - just need to add this line: `GROUP BY users.user_id` before order by

Answer (score -1):

Try

```
ORDER BY msgid DESC LIMIT 1
```

Comment: Lool. ORDER BY msgid DESC LIMIT 1 = simply gives you 1 output in DESCENDING order out of 10 for example

Comment: The question does necessarily wants to have distinct values. When two or more rows have the same user_id, the output should give you only 1 distinct user_id from the same rows not LIMIT.